# How to get the "Modified by" data in a SearchKit query?

Tags: searchkit, user-account, logs

In a SearchKit query, how can we get the values of the field "Modified by" that can be seen in the change log of a contact? For what is worth, we have advanced logging enabled ("Logging: Yes" in settings).

I want to build a "Recent Changes" saved search. This is the closest I'm getting:

- Search for: Contacts and Contact Logs (I have tried with Contact Reports as well)
- Where Modified Date is Last 7 Days Including Today (this works)
- Display Name for the Contact Modified (this works)
- Modified Date for the date modified (this works)
- "Contact Logs: Modified By Display Name" only shows data when the user modifies their own contact card. If they modify other contact cards, this value is empty.

I can see the Modified By / Altered By logs in the contact cards. I have tried with values from Contact Reports but they don't bring any values. What am I missing?

I thought it could be a problem of permissions but I'm an admin and "Bypass Permissions" in the table won't make any difference.

If there is an entirely different way to get a list of Recent Changes, that would be useful to know too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advanced logging tables do not have an api4 entity. Even if they did, the civireport that shows you the changes uses a diffing algorithm you'd have to somehow replicate because the advanced logs do not store *changes*, they store *copies* of the changed record.

What you're able to get in your description is coming from various fields on the contact record and from civicrm_log (the Log api4 entity - which is not the advanced logging and just has some basic info). I don't think you'll be able to get much more than what you've got, except you haven't mentioned Advanced Search - it has a changelog section which is basically the same as civicrm_log, but you can make a saved search from it.

Comment: Thank you for confirming what isn't possible nowadays. I will try Advanced Search + Profile, then.